# Detection of reload button pressed in Java Script

Tags: javascript, object-detection, reload

How to detect whether the reload button is pressed and after that the the processes be held and after that reload. Like when reload is pressed or Ctrl + R then I want to save that it is reloaded in local storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event handler for processing `onbeforeunload` events is the `WindowEventHandlers` mixin's `onbeforeunload` property. When a window is about to unload its resources, these events are triggered.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(m) {
  return 'Your Statement';
};
```

And you can refer to Mozilla docs for more because you didn't shared your source code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

To save localStorage in browser on reload/refresh of page.

Add Javascript code as below

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert(localStorage.variable) //comment this line to avoid alert box
    localStorage.setItem("variable", "set a variable value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the page on which you are currently running a script has been reloaded before, you can use [PerformanceNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type) or more recently [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type):

```js
performance?.getEntriesByType("navigation")?.[0]?.type === "reload" || performance.navigation.type === PerformanceNavigation.TYPE_RELOAD
```

If that is too verbose, you can omit the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the constant:

```js
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation").[0].type === "reload" || performance.navigation.type === 1
```

And if you only want to support modern browsers, you can leave out the second part.

I'm unsure what the intention is to use the local storage, but maybe you even don't need to save this because you know it right away.

The navigation objects also contain more informations like redirectCount which might be interesting, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**performance. navigation. type**" to determine whether the reload button is pressed.

This attribute returns an integer value indicating the source of loading the web page. There are four possible cases:

0: The web page is loaded by clicking the link, entering the address bar, submitting the form, and operating the script, which is equivalent to the constant **performance.navigation.TYPE_ NAVIGATE**.

1: The web page is loaded through the "Reload" button or the location. reload() method, which is equivalent to the constant **performance.navigation.TYPE_ RELOAD**.

2: The web page is loaded through the "forward" or "backward" button, which is equivalent to the constant **performance.navigation.TYPE_ BACK_ FORWARD**.

255: Loading from any other source is equivalent to the constant **performance.navigation.TYPE_ RESERVED**.

**Performance.navigation.redirectCount**: indicates the number of times the page has been redirected.

However, you need to pay attention to the browser compatibility of performance.navigation.type.

If you want to save the state, you can use sessionStorage or cookies.

Comment: [Performance.navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) is deprecated, don't use it.